# Windows 10 eventually changes time to UTC

Tags: windows, time, time-synchronization

I have 9 Windows 10 clients for whom I can not set the time. I proceed to date and time, change the time to the current time and timezone and then within an hour the time reverts to what appears to be UTC even though the timezone stays the same. I have disabled the Time service and attempted to statically assign the date and time. I have specified a time server in our corporate domain that return the correct time, but no matter what I do, I can not set the time to last longer than an hour. Is this normal? I am thinking about setting a Task Scheduler to resynchronize every 5 minutes as I have software that must be synchronized. Could another task be changing the time? Could an anti-virus do this? I am an administrator on all these machines.

Comment: Is UTC time of the machine changing, or the display for a user?  You can check UTC time in PowerShell with [DateTime]::UtcNow

Comment: Anything in event logs? (check System)

Answer (score -1):

Check date and time in BIOS.  Windows 10 sees BIOS date and time.  Whatever the change made in BIOS will reflect in Operating System.